# If a<x<b and C<y<d and x>y return value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, range, return-value

Can some one explain if this is correct in JavaScript?
Or how to achieve that?

X - constant imput
y - constant imput
X>Y

If ay return value

Option 1: `if (100=<x=<500 & 1=<y=<7) return 5;`

Or

Option 2: `if (100<=x & x=<5000 & 12<=y & y<17) return 5;`

Comment: None of them are correct. The "less than or equal" operator is `<=` not `=<`. Option 2 is close, but `&` should be `&&`; the two operators are different.

Comment: Also, your using a bitwise operator & instead of the logical &&

Comment: I tried this but don't work:
if (x<=100 && x<=500 && y<=1 && y<=7) return 5;

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if (x >= 100 && x <= 5000 && y >= 12 && y<17) return 5;
```

To be able to return something, you need to use this statement within a function. Otherwise, you need to define what you want to do with the 5.